# Graphql subscriptions client-side http request

Tags: graphql, subscription

Is it possible to use subscriptions with simple http requests similarly to query,mutation where I just have to send a POST request with "application/graphql" Content-Type, and body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, it is not possible to do it.

In GraphQL, `subscriptions` are subscribing to a `websocket` and listening to data changes and it reacts to custom events, so it is not something you can query with a POST request.

As stated on the documentation at [Apollo Client Subscriptions](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/subscriptions.html).

> Now, queries and mutations will go over HTTP as normal, but subscriptions will be done over the websocket transport.